# Removing from what is in the bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Using LyX with `biblatex-apa`. I am trying to remove the parentheses that surround the article, book, collection, etc year in the references. I just want the format to be `YEAR.` instead of `(YEAR).`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@article{art1,
 Author = {John Smith},
 Year = {1998},
 Publisher = {XYZ},
 Title = {ABC}
 }
@book{book1,
 Author = {Jane Smith},
 Year = {2009},
 Publisher = {ABC},
 Title = {XYZ}
 }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\begin{document}

text \cite{art1}
text \cite{book1}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I tried removing them using: `\DeclareFieldFormat{year}{#1}` in the preamble but nothing changed

Comment: So how are you trying to remove them? Please post a Minimum Working Example showing what you've tried.

Comment: @cfr Thanks, all set. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To format a special field you can work the the command `\DeclareFieldFormat`. In your contents you have to do the following:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{yearorunkyear}{%
  \ifthenelse{\iffieldequalstr{doubtfuldate}{true}}
    {\mkbibbrackets{ca\adddot\addspace#1}}
    {#1}}
```

If you use this redefinition you will get the following output:

> [image]